# ¿Como usar bootstrap instalado con npm?

Tags: javascript, nodejs

Estoy iniciando en *NodeJS* e instalé *bootstrap* mediante:

```
npm i bootstrap
```

Esto me dejo solo una carpeta dentro de node modules que se llama bootstrap... En mi archivo *HTML* llame **`bootstrap.css`** como un *CSS* normal, es decir:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css" type="text/css" media="all">
```

Pero no funciona, no se si debo hacer algo en un archivo js, o debo llamarlo de alguna otra forma. Ahora me esta arrojando el error:

> Refused to apply style from 'http://localhost:3000/node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.

Y dentro de ese enlace me dice:

> Cannot GET /node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css

Sé que podría usar el CDN pero quiero aprender a hacerlo desde *npm*.

Comment: tal vez este enlace te ayude: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22792254/how-do-i-load-bootstrap-using-npm

Comment: Hola, Bootstrap es una librería diseñada para crear proyectos web *responsive*. Es claro que estás desarrollando con NodeJS, pero imagino que usarás algún Framework (Angular, React, Vue) si trabajarás con el FrontEnd, sin embargo si vas a realizar un proyecto para BackEnd, de ¿qué manera pretendes usar Bootstrap? ¿Podrías aclarar eso un poco? Saludos

Answer (score 0):

A mí me funciona escribir esta ruta:

```
<link href="../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

Aunque la ruta variará dependiendo de la estructura de carpetas de tu proyecto, pero lo importante es que tienes que indicar que apuntar al archivo `bootstrap.min.css` que esta dentro de la carpeta `node_modules` según esta ruta:

```
node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css
```